# Constructing a grid of individual plots for data imported from a list of files

Tags: plotting, import

I have to plot 6 data plots (`ListPlot`) in a `GraphicsGrid` from 6 different files (each data file has four columns of which the first one is $x$-data and the other 3 are functions of $x$). All data files are similar to one another. I am using many options in each `ListPlot`.

Is there a way to use some kind of loop to plot these files in a grid (3x3 grid)? I have tried with following code using a `For` loop but I am stuck at some point. Here is the code I tried.

[image]

Comment: Please post Mathematica code instead of screen-captures of your code so that users here can copy and paste your code into their MMA notebooks. It makes it more likely for your question to be answered. Click the circled question mark at the right of the tool bar when editing your question for help with formatting.

Answer (score 3):

an example of a grid of plots:

```
GraphicsGrid[
       Partition[Table[ Plot[Sin[i x] , {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {i, 7}],
             3,  3 , {1, 1}, Null]]
```

[image]

then for your case it will be something like:

```
GraphicsGrid[
       Partition[Table[
         p=ReadList[];
         ...
         ListPlot[...], {i, Length[datasource]}],
             3,  3 , {1, 1}, Null]]
```